# Using sendMail is regularly returning 429 error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My application sends emails on behalf of an Office 365 customer using the Graph API. Functionally this works great except the volume of email being sent can be somewhat high at times at which point the emails will stop being sent by the Graph API due to being throttled. The problem is that there is no explanation for when the emails are suddenly no longer going to be sent. Instead a 429 error code is just suddenly returned. I have tried lots of different methods to slow down the emails but I still randomly get 429s returned. I need a method to reliably send email. Either a way to avoid a 429 or is there a way for the Office 365 customer to authorize an account to not be subjected to throttling such that as many emails as necessary can be sent? I can't find any documentation regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to get throttling limits adjusted or removed for the Graph API. AFAIK, the throttling limits are not published as the limits may change without notice, probably to preserve service health.

Does the 429 provide any backoff guidance? What is the maximum rate for sending email?

**Answer to my first question**: There is a Retry-After response header which indicates how long the application should wait until it resubmits the request.

Comment: The response is that it is an unkown error. So no guidance provided. I have limited the rate to a maximum of 1 email per second.

Comment: Can you share the full 429 error message please?  It really should have a Retry-After property in the HTTP header response.

Comment: {  "error": {    "code": "UnknownError",    "message": "",    "innerError": {      "request-id": "1c22d5ad-2761-4a33-a57d-24d03406f955",      "date": "2017-01-30T18:09:02"    }  }}

Comment: In my experience, too, for what I was trying on Microsoft Graph there are no published limits, no back-off guidance, no retry-after properties.  In fact, there's nothing at all except this frustrating 429 unknown error message.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to one of the comments my mistake occurred to me.  I wasn't paying careful enough attention to the *header* part of *HTTP header response* and I was mistaken in thinking that no Retry-After property was being sent.  It's, of course, in the header, not in the body of the response.  I'm using node.js so it was a matter of checking res.headers in my code upon receiving an error.

Now I can safely configure my application to restart after being throttled, by making the timeout between requests equal to the Retry-After property.